# Ignore parent Provider Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to ignore a parent providers that it has in it's module, without reorganizing my whole project structure. My searchGrid component let says, can use both of the provided services but I only want my child to use the Provided SEARCH_DATA and use/ignore the GRID_REDIRECT at all.

Thanks for the help.

```
//Parent Module
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SearchPageComponent,
        SearchGridComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       ChildModule
       SearchModule
       RedirectModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: SEARCH_DATA,
            useExisting: SearchGridTypeService,
        },
        {
            provide: GRID_REDIRECT,
            useExisting: SEARCH_DATA,
        },
    ],
})
export class ParentModule {}
```

Child Module

```
//Child Module
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SearchChildPageComponent,
        SearchGridComponent
    ],
    imports: [
              SearchModule
],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: SEARCH_DATA,
            useExisting: SearchGridTypeService,
        },
    ],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code won't work as Angular will merge all `providers` together, first your Child, then your Parent, your Parent will always win ([`import`ed modules](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular) take less precedence).

As you present the whole module, not a single service, I can only think of lazy-loaded module. By default, lazy-loaded module will use its own service.
You can think of `forRoot` and `forChild` as in the router module, as `forRoot` is for services that are available for the whole project, and `forChild` is for feature modules only.

You can read more about `forRoot pattern` [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forRoot)